# Output specific rows from csv

Tags: linux, csv, sed, awk, grep

I have a very large (500mb) csv file and another textfile containing one word per line.

When I find a word in the textfile in the csv **in a specific collumn** I want to output the line (will redirect output to a file). I had a grep solution using grep -iE "(word1|word2|word3|...|wordn)" but it crashed after using 16gb memory with a segfault and only extracted very few entries.

I tried csvtool but it refuses to produce anything valueable.

The solution must work under linux and optimally not cap on memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`. Process the file with one word per line first, save its data in an array and for the second file check the specific column using the expression ***if (column in array)***:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = ",";
    }
    FNR == NR {
        data[ $1 ] = 1;
        next;
    }
    FNR < NR {
        if ( $4 in data ) {
            print $0;
        }
    }
' textfile large_csv_file
```

Comment: sorry I have never used awk. Where do I specify the column I want to check? my guess is if($4 in data){ . is the $4 the column number? if yes, is it zero-indexed starting at column 0?

Comment: @Birei Worked and was lightning fast. One little error: Instead of FNR < NR I had to use NF > 1. Thank you.